# How to check if json keys are from an allowed set in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql

`'{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}'::jsonb ?& array['a', 'b']` checks if right hand side, an array of text, is contained by the top-level keys of the left hand side.

How can I check the opposite? That is, whether the keys of the json string are from a known set of texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the keys of your object with [`json(b)_object_keys`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) and collect them into an array. Then use the [array contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
array(SELECT jsonb_object_keys('{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}'::jsonb)) <@ array['a', 'b']
```

Alternatively, you could use a subquery on the keys and conjugate tests against the array (equivalent to the `NOT EXISTS` check by @GMB):

```
SELECT bool_and(k = ANY(array['a', 'b'])) FROM jsonb_object_keys(object) as k
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=58e46fe918db419a1b9d8848cf446d4e))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_object_keys()` and `ANY` like so:

```
select 1
from jsonb_object_keys(t.js) o(x)
where not x = ANY(ar)
```

**[Here is](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dcb7021fb6b6f5bd555b8190e58585ad)** how to use this in a query:

```
with t as (
    select '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}'::jsonb js, array['a', 'b', 'c'] ar
    union all select '{"a":1, "b":2, "z":3}'::jsonb js, array['a', 'b'] ar
)
select 
    js,
    ar,
    not exists(
        select 1
        from jsonb_object_keys(t.js) o(x)
        where not x = ANY(ar)
    ) res
from t
```

Yields:

```
js                       | ar      | res
:----------------------- | :------ | :-----
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} | {a,b,c} | true  
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "z": 3} | {a,b}   | false
```